# Solution of This Integral Calculus

Tags: calculus

I changed my [earlier problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/55949/solution-of-this-complicated-formula).
$$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{x^a}\frac{1}{e^{ibA\ln{x}}}dx$$

$i$ is imaginary unit, $a$,$b$,$A$ is constant.

Any answer will be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: This integral is just $\int_0^1 x^{-(a+ibA)} \, dx$.

Comment: What is the motivation for this problem? Is it homework, or is it something you actually came across in some real-world application? Why do you have both a constant $b$ and a constant $A$, when only their product appears in the integral? Please show some partial work so we can see that you've made some effort. I'm downvoting because this fits exactly within the criterion shown in the pop-up help box for the downvote button: "This question does not show any research effort..."

Comment: I would suggest the substitution $x:=e^{-u}$ $\ (\infty> u\geq 0)$. In this way you don't have to deal with strange things like $x^{a+i b A}$ for variable $x$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I still can't comment but isn't this simply equal to

$$
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{x^a}\frac{1}{e^{ibA\ln{x}}}dx &= \int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{x^a}\frac{1}{(e^{\ln{x}})^{ibA}}dx\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{x^a}\frac{1}{x^{ibA}}dx\\
&= \int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{x^{a+ibA}}dx\\
\end{align}
$$
for $x>0$.

Comment: Why can't you comment? Do you see the "add comment" button?

Comment: @Patrick Da Silva : I can only comment on my own answer as I am doing now. Other than that, "add comment" is disabled for me. Besides, it didn't feel like an answer but anyway, not a big deal. I see that your answer was faster than mine so sorry for not noticing on time.

Comment: @Patrick: You need 50 reputation to comment (see http://math.stackexchange.com/privileges/comment).

Comment: Don't worry for putting a second answer, it's not a big deal at all. It happens all the time.

Comment: @joriki : XD I guess I didn't stay there long enough to notice... lol

Answer (score 3):

This integral is just $\int_0^1 x^{-(a+ibA)} \, dx$. Since you can re-write
$$
e^{ibA \ln(x)} = (e^{\ln(x)})^{ibA} = x^{ibA},
$$
you get the above integral and the result follows quite easily since we know antiderivatives for powers of $x$.

Hope that helps,